# Teradata Viewpoint on Teradata Express 16.10 is not working

Tags: teradata

I understand we have multiple post regarding viewpoint is not working on TD Express but didn't find solution on it and also those people have issues in starting the viewpoint using `vp-control.sh start` command but my issue is different.

I have installed TD Express 16.10 and everything is working perfectly except viewpoint.

I used `Viewpoint Start` icon to start the viewpoint and it started without any issue,

[image]

I also checked the status of viewpoint using `vp-control.sh status` and all services are running except the viewpoint is `Unused`

[image]

Then I tried to open Viewpoint in firefox provided in the image of TD Express by entering the various options like `localhost\c` , `127.0.0.1\c` , `127.0.0.1:80`,etc but Viewpoint did not open,

[image]

I tried `wget localhost` then I could discover that it failed to establish connection,

[image]

Can someone guide me or point any issues that I am not able to understand here, As per below post, it looks straight forward but it is not,

https://downloads.teradata.com/database/articles/teradata-express-14-0-for-vmware-user-guide

Comment: Why use 14.0 User Guide with 16.10 TD Express? If you refer to the 16.10 User Guide you will see that the default 4GB memory size for the VM is not sufficient to run Viewpoint. (That's the most common reason for Viewpoint to fail to start.)

Comment: @Fred Good catch :) My memory size for the VM is 4 GB but I cannot increase it as if i shutdown the VM then data will be lost, I tried by suspending the VM but the option to increase the memory size is disabled.

Comment: Do an orderly shutdown: `tpareset -x "increasing memory size"` to stop the database, use `pdestate` to check progress and wait until status is DOWN/HARDSTOP then `init 0`.

Comment: If I shutdown with this order and also shutdown the VM after that to increase the memory size then data will persist, right?

Comment: Correct. The `init 0` will stop the Linux OS and "power down" the VM so you can make changes. When you power up, reboot, and restart the database, all your objects and contents will still be there.

Comment: I followed the steps and could increase the RAM to 8 GB from 4 GB but issue still persist, viewpoint status is started cannot open it from firefox. :(

Comment: Does `vp-control.sh status` now say Viewpoint is running? If so, it may just take quite a while for Viewpoint to initialize, especially if you have just 2 CPU cores assigned to the VM. Let it run for an hour or so.

Comment: It worked with external IP from outer machine, but now I cannot setup the system to monitor because it does not accept TDPid other than local :(

Comment: VIewpoint on TD Express is limited to only monitoring that "local" instance. But any of: dbc, localhost, 127.0.0.1 should work for that. It's the name that the Viewpoint instance can use to connect to the local database.