# Teradata Express Does not respond after restart

Tags: teradata

Instead of commenting on thread [Teradata Viewpoint on Teradata Express 16.10 is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57556867/teradata-viewpoint-on-teradata-express-16-10-is-not-working?noredirect=1#comment102368715_57556867), I am creating new thread but it is with respect to linked so added this link to post,

I have restarted Teradata Express with command `tpareset -x "increasing memory size"` and increased the memory, but after restart, queries on system are running very slowly and sometimes SQl Assistant goes into `Not Respoding` state.

To resolve this temporary, I used `tpa stop` and then `tpa start`, after this, system runs smoothly without lag but sometimes later it again goes into slow state.

Not sure what is happening here, can someone guide on how to resolve it permanently ?

Comment: @Fred : I have created new thread

Comment: What's the RAM of your host system and RAM assigned to your VM? Check memory usage in Task Manager (if running Windows)

Comment: @dnoeth RAM assigned to host system is 80 GB and to VM, It's 8 GB.

Comment: 80GB? Then simply increase VM RAM to at least 12 GB, better 16 GB. Start Viewpoint first and then Teradata.

Comment: Can you give me pointers on how to start viewpoint first before teradata in Teradata Express?

Comment: If Teradata is already running, do the `tpareset -x` first to shutdown Teradata, then use the icons to start Viewpoint, wait a minute and then start TD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199667/discussion-between-shawn-and-dnoeth).